# Scroll para abajo cuando hago click

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, scroll

Quiero que el scroll vaya hasta abajo del sitio (o por lo menos 100px) cuando hago clic en el calendario, para poder ver las opciones de reserva.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código, pero no hace nada y en el debugger de Chrome no me muestra ningún error.  ¿Alguna idea? El código lo estoy poniendo en el header.php (Wordpress)

Sitio: http://sparkkstudio.com/havanacubatours/tours/city-tour-santiago-de-cuba-morro-cobre/

```
$('.ui-state-default').click(function () {
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(document).height()
   }, 'slow');
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error:
>
> Al incluirlo en `header.php` tu `script` se esta ejecutando cuando aún no se termino de cargar por completo la página y el elemento con clase `.ui-state-default` aún no existe.

Solución:

Has uso de [`$(function(){})`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) para que tu `script` se ejecute en el `onload`.

Por ejemplo así:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.ui-state-default').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-state-default {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer
}
.ui-state-default:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f99;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <a class="ui-state-default">Ir al fondo</a>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="blog-header">
        <h1 class="blog-title">The Bootstrap Blog</h1>
        <p class="lead blog-description">The official example template of creating a blog with Bootstrap.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">

          <div class="blog-post">
            <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
            <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

            <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that's supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
            <blockquote>
              <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong> ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
          </div><!-- /.blog-post -->

        </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
        </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

      </div><!-- /.row -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <footer class="blog-footer">
      <p>Blog template built for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a> by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
    </footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Disculpen, para que se ubiquen mejor este es el enlace del sitio http://sparkkstudio.com/havanacubatours/tours/city-tour-santiago-de-cuba-morro-cobre/ todavía no probé sus respuestas. Gracias de antemano

Comment: El div al que quiero hacer el scroll no existe cuando se carga el sitio. El div se crea cuando hago clic en alguna fecha del calendario, por eso justamente necesito que el scroll sea en px. El codigo lo puse ahora al principio del js que genera ese contenido (http://sparkkstudio.com/havanacubatours/wp-content/themes/BookYourTravel/js/tours.js)

Answer (score 0):

te dejo este codigo

```
$(function () {
            $('#verMas').bind("click", function () {
                var dest = $("#one").offset().top;
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: dest},600);
            });

        });
```

"#verMas" es el id del boton donde haces el click
"#one" es el div al que quieres llegar